# Caching Chromebooks updates: on premise caching from non proxy-configured client?

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid, http-caching, chrome-os

Before even attempting to setup something that wouldn't work, I'd like to understand if the following configuration has a logic.

Basically we want to stop Chromebooks to steal bandwidth on updates.
Google suggests to setup a local web caching server so that requests to `dl.google.com` are cached in LAN, saving 400mb online requests per each Chromebook.

This could be done setting up a local web caching proxy (squid?) and declare this as a proxy in the Chromebook configuration, however, as I would like to limit request to the local web caching server only for `dl.google.com` and nothing else, I thought I could create a local DNS record on the LAN's DNS server, so that requests to `dl.google.com` are forwarded to the local proxy.

In your opinion, will this work, or will the proxy refuse/ignore requests from hosts that are not intrinsically configured to use a proxy?

Comment: Did you implement this caching system?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jordan Dalley](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jordan-dalley-a7932611/), who tweaked an [Nginx LanCache](https://github.com/tsvcathed/nginx_lancache) configuration,

> "on premises caching or micro-CDN solution for Microsoft, Google and
> Adobe products"

we are now using a tiny CentOS virtualised machine, which is exclusively dedicated to local caching purposes.
Caching is done transparently and working perfectly.

Thanks Jordan for helping me!

P.S. - Follow [this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/k12sysadmin/comments/keys0e/chromebook_updates_best_strategy_to_avoid_network/gg5dat2/?context=3)